# How do I use the jQuery, Waypoints extension on a Click Event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-waypoints

I'm reading the documentation here: [jQuery, Waypoints, plugin docs](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/#documentation).

And I'd like to refresh the waypoints using this jQuery object extension on a click event:

```
$.waypoints('refresh')
```

How do you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click-event on what?

Suppose you add a button to the page:

```
<button id="refreshWaypointsBtn" type="button">Refresh the waypoints.</button>
```

Then you'd activate it like so:

```
$("#$refreshWaypointsBtn").click ( function () {
    $.waypoints ('refresh');
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#$refreshWaypointsBtn').on('click', function() {
     Waypoint.refreshAll();
});
```